# How to sum multiple values from firebase (android kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How can I sum multiple values from this database?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. You can get this for the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the value with `n.getValue(Int::class.java)`. But as the screenshot shows, you've stored the numbers as strings, so `getValue` will return null here.

To fix that problem, you'll want to get the string and *then* convert it to a number:

```
n.getValue(String::class.java).toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in **Firebase Realtime Database** as **Strings**.
The values should be stored as Integers or Long.

but since as per your screenshots, the data is already stored as Strings, the data you get needs to be converted to Integer or Long.

***Another Error that I see is you have not initialized mCountList.***

```
private var mCountList :ArrayList<Int>? = null
```

***A better approach would be***

```
override fun onDataChange(p0:DataSnapshot){

   // x to store all the integer values recieved from Firebase
   val x = arrayListOf<Int>()
   // sum to store the Sum of all the values recieved from Firebase 
   var sum = 0

   for(i in p0.children){
      val value = i.value as Int

      x.add(value)
      sum +=  value
   }

  // if you want you can store x data in mCountList
  mCountList = x

  // Display Sum with Toast
  Toast.makeText(context, "total $sum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```